# The set of points that derivative of $f(x)=\inf\{|y-x|:y\in A\}$ not exist

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots\}$ and $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be function that $f(x)=\inf\{|y-x|:y\in A\}$. Also let $K$ be the set of points that $f'$ not exist. Is $K$ is closed?Is $K$ is compact?Is every point in $K$ is isolated?

Comment: what is $f(3/4)$? or shall $K$ be the set where $f$ is not a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n\geq 1$. Take $x$ in $[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$. Compute $f(x)$. You might want to consider the midpoint of this interval and treat two cases. Then do the cases $x\leq 0$ and $x\geq 1$. Now determine $K$. Don't hesitate to draw the graph of $f$.